# How to create kubeconfig for a new principle to be used in github pipeline only

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I want to run, from github pipeline/runner, kubectl to automatically deploy my apps to the EKS cluster.

I see this [tutorial](https://dev.to/leandronsp/deploy-to-kubernetes-using-github-actions-including-slack-notification-11je) that append the principle `kubernetes-github-actions` to the `~/.kube/config` file and then put that whole file to the `secrets` (together with an API key for the k8s API for that princple) in Github and uses that to issue `kubectl` commands to the EKS cluster.

Is there a way to simply generate a new `config` file only for the principle `kubernetes-github-actions` instead of appending? I see in this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) some examples but it's not clear how to generate a separate config only for the new principle that I want to use in Github only. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: You can use the AWS CLI to create a kubeconfig, e.g. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <name> --kubeconfig <alternate-config-file>. You can edit the exec/args block under users to specify the principle/role you want to use or you can use the --role-arn flag with update-kubeconfig.